# Are there any good alternatives to PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I'm testing some legacy code and tried PowerMock for mocking static method calls. I quickly found out that it messes with classloaders and it is not the kind of problem I feel qualified to dig into. FYI my problem is similar to [this](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=299) but solution posted there doesn't work in my case.

Are there any good alternatives to PowerMock that I can try which are capable of mocking statics, compatible with TestNG and are successfully used in some live projects?

I know that the best alternative is testable code but it's not always possible to refactor my current project.

Comment: jmockit is one option (can mock static methods) - its [about page](http://jmockit.org/about.html) lists several alternatives.

Comment: if you're adding new unit tests - why not use the opportunity to refactor everything around what you want to test to comply with sane testing procedures?

Comment: @rmalchow I'd love to refactor all the way :) but currently we have yet to come to an agreement in my team to which extent should we embrace refactoring to minimize risks of breaking smth. Meanwhile I was asked to see if there is an alternative that doesn't cause so many problems as PowerMock.

Comment: @assylias thank you, jmockit looks like a thing to try out.

Comment: The link to the jmockit no longer works, jmockit is currently here: http://jmockit.github.io/ but there doesn't seem to be a list of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- Use a different in-process mocking tool that allows for static mocking such as Mockito ([Mockito supports mocking static methods since version 3.4.0](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v3.4.0)) to see if the problems you have highlighted go away. It is likely though it's not a tool problem but a methodology problem, so please read the next point.
- Use [over-the-wire test doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) instead of in-process mocks, that way you can test your application black-box and do not have to use static mocks or refactor code. You achieve that by stubbing or mocking dependent systems instead of focusing on individual classes or methods

  - example of an OpenSource tool that supports HTTP over-the-wire stubbing/mocking is [Wiremock](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Wiremock-testing-mocking-over-wire-stubs/)
  - example of a commercial tool that supports multiple protocols like HTTP, gRPC and JMS is [Traffic Parrot](https://trafficparrot.com/)
  - you can find more tools that do [over-the-wire mocking and stubbing on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools)